# Express get api with params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to express API. I have an API with http GET and I'd like to get data from mongodb that matches to certain criteria. Here is my mongodb documents looks like :

`{value:"24", category:"low"} {value:"30", category:"middle"}, {value:"23", category:"low"}`

And my code in the server side looks like this :

```
`router.route('/temps')
.get(function(req,res){
    Temp.find(function(err, temps){
      if(err){
        res.send(err)
      } else {
        var category = req.params.category
        console.log(temps)
        res.format({
          json: function(){
            res.json(temps)
          },
          html: function(){
          res.render('temps', {
                  title: 'All temps',
                  temps: temps
              });
          },
        });
      }
    })
  })`
```

I wanna get all values where the category is `low` with query like this : `/temps?category=low`. How can I modify the codes above? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check for `req.params.category` then your route should be `/temp/:category`  for example, `/temp/low` because `req.params` is for path parameters.

If you want to check for query parameters like `/temp?category=low` then you should check for `req.query.category`

Comment: best!~ very helpful